# Filtering null objects in Java 8

Tags: java-8

I have a list of Request objects in which few null fields are acceptable(and can be used) and few objects cannot be null and should be flagged.

In the below sample code below, if Id is null, it should be printed and should not continue with that request object and if date is null, it is acceptable. How could this be filtered in Java 8

```
class Request {

private String id;
private String name;
private Date createDate;

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Date getCreateDate() {
    return createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
}
}
```

Code snippet 2:

```
List<Request> list = new ArrayList<Request>();
Request req1 = new Request();
Request req2 = new Request();
req1.setId(null); //null not allowed in Id
req1.setName("test1");
req1.setCreateDate(new Date());
req2.setId("2");
req2.setName("test2");
req2.setCreateDate(null); //null allowed in date
list.add(req1);
list.add(req2);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "filtered" and "flagged"? You could just add a null check to the set method for fields that shouldn't accept null.

Comment: By the way, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). See `Instant` class.

Comment: Do you need a new list? If your source is a mutable list like `ArrayList`, you may remove them and notify like `if(list.removeIf(r -> r.getId() == null)) System.out.println("There were requests with null ID which have been removed");`…

Comment: @basil-boursque Thanks. I will check that out

Comment: @Holger I simply cannot remove and ignore them. I will have to do some more action with the null requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your Request class needs getter for ID:

```
public void getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Now, you can filter by id attribute:

```
list.stream().filter(r -> r.getId() != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I went on with this answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

// You have to add getter method for id. then you can use below line to print object which id is not null

list.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() != null).forEach(c -> System.out.println(" id --> "+c.getName()+" name --> "+c.getName()+" createDate --> "+c.getCreateDate()));

For more detail you can check [here!](http://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/java-8-stream-filter-example)

Comment: Thanks for your time.